# Use HttpUrlBuilder in gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following function to build Url.

```
public String buildURL(Departments department) {
        URL url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("http")
                .host("localhost")
                .port(Integer.valueOf(department.getPort()))
                .addPathSegments(department.getName()+"/synchronization")
                .build().url();
        return url.toString();
    }
```

In build.gradle I use dependencies.

```
compile group: 'com.squareup.okio', name: 'okio', version: '1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0
```

When I try to call function above I get the following error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/central] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Buffer] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okio.Buffer
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: follow owner of API in github:https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen    may be he will help very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add dependencies to the `buildscript` section so that they are available to the build itself, not the module being compiled:

```
buildscript {
    repositories.jcenter()
    dependencies.add("classpath", "com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0")
    dependencies.add("classpath", "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0")
}

URL url = new okhttp3.HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host("localhost")
    .port(3333)
    .addPathSegments("address")
    .build().url()
```

Comment: Adding `System.out.println(url)` to the above I am getting: `➜  ./gradlew assemble --no-daemon --gradle-user-home=../.gradle
> Configure project : http://localhost:3333/address` Your error must be elsewhere

Comment: Problem lies in another place. I have duplicated modules shared the same library. I removed not used and it works.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped